# Viability of React Native

Tags: android, react-native

We are a team of 5 members, one of us having basic knowledge of Android App Development. We are planning to develop an app having functionalities similar to Uber. Following are some things we have in mind:

- Building one app through react native, where our concern is the availability of Maps and other API's in React Native.
- Or developing native apps for IOS and Android platform.

What would be the better case, considering that we are beginners to    app    development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone that writes both native iOS and react native apps I can say the following:

- react native excels in speed of "net" development time. > 90% of the code is cross platform and there is no need to build your project after every change (one of the biggest pains in mobile development IMO)
- however, most of my efforts in my current RN project are dealing with technical issues, compatibility of different packages & breaking changes. the entire ecosystem is less mature, development tools are inferior and there is way less documentation.

RN fits my particular, relatively simple, project and it allowed me to write for both platforms wo knowing Java\Kotlin. I would think twice before starting a more complicated project in RN.

BTW, Airbnb that wrote the above mention react-native-maps, recently announced they're sunsetting RN development: https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/sunsetting-react-native-1868ba28e30a

EDIT: I found myself wring a full blown production app in RN for the past 9 months and this is my current perspective:

- RN is constantly evolving. The facebook team is doing an incredible job making the platform better.
- Javascript can be tamed using typescript and working with design patterns (Im using redux-saga)
- We use one codebase and repository for FE & BE: that's the biggest advantage IMO. The entire team is using the same language, we can review each other code and assist in tasks.
- It may require some hacking but I have yet to encounter a situation where I couldn't achieve something that was required by product in RN.
- The only real downside with RN is performance. By design, RN is less performant than native apps. For many apps, the difference will be negligible but if your app is heavy on animations, this is something to consider. The FB team are working on a big architectural change that's supposed to address this. (rumours say that the version of RN FB are using internally is way more performant).

Comment: Thank you, it really helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If development effort/cost is not a matter for the organization, just go ahead with option 2: Developing native iOS & Android using swift and JAVA. Native development have access to complete capabilities of mobile development. It is very rich in UI design, performance, scalability and many other things. Lot of support and tutorial available in internet if you stuck in middle.

Option 1, Developing on react native: If majority of developers are experts in web development, java script and React JS please go ahead. It requires less development effort because one project will support for both android and ios. In this option, still you need native app development knowledge to develop custom, complex views and exported to React native.

Explore through internet to know the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it because React-native-maps is good npm module for maps

You can find [Github](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps)
 doc here

It works great for android and ios

And more answer here: [Which is best map to use on react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520114/which-is-best-map-to-use-on-react-native)

But, in personal opinion i love native app, it's the best.